# Apache won't start Centos 7, no errors journal -xe

Tags: nginx, web-server, apache-2.4, httpd, centos7

I cannot say when it started because I recently moved and just finished setting up my lab.  Though when booting up the VM w/ my NGINX / Apache Server I did a yum update and Apache was upgraded, now it is no longer starting and not issuing an error either.  I can't say if it happened before or after the upgrade, nor do I remember the old version I was running.  I know that lack of information is probably not helping... Normally, it has advised me when I had a syntax issue or a missing module, etc.  Also I checked the audit.log for the PID below and it nothing was there either, so I don't believe SELinux is blocking it either.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
May 31 01:33:16 webserver.home systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
May 31 01:33:16 webserver.home systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 31 01:33:16 webserver.home kill[10202]: kill: cannot find process ""
May 31 01:33:16 webserver.home systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 31 01:33:16 webserver.home systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
May 31 01:33:16 webserver.home systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
May 31 01:33:16 webserver.home systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.


[root@webserver /]# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   May 12 2016 10:27:23
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
[root@webserver /]# httpd -t
Syntax OK
[root@webserver /]# httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
```

Comment: Anything appearing in the error_logs? If you have vhosts defined with Error_Log directives, this may not be the main log.

Comment: Thanks I eventually found the error in the error_log, it seemed that it did not have permission to access the log file of the virtual host due to SELinux even though I didn't see anything in the log initially.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the error in the error_log, it seemed that it did not have permission to access the log file of the virtual host due to SELinux even though I didn't see anything in the audit log initially.